# SDL_LoadBMP() failed: Couldn't open .bmp

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

SDL_RenderCopy returns -1 with SDL_GetError(): `SDL_RenderCopy(): Invalid texture`

"Couldn't open /images/character.bmp"

Passes NULL to text when SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()

Here is my code:

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

SDL_Surface *surf = SDL_LoadBMP("/images/character.bmp");

if (surf == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Load bmp failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
}

SDL_Texture *text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surf);

//check if texture is NULL
if (text == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Creating texture failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
}

SDL_Rect rect = {500, 600, 330, 450};

int quit = 0;
while (!quit) {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    //problem here
    if (SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, text, NULL, &rect) < 0) {
        printf("Error in RenderCopy(): %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Comment: Add some error checks & edit in a [mcve].  For all we know `text` is `NULL`.

Comment: You can add `if (text == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "CreateTextureFromSurface failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError()); exit(1); }` after creating the texture to get more information.

Comment: Does a [`fopen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) on that absolute `/images/character.bmp` path succeed?  If it fails, what does [`perror()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror) print after it?

Comment: perror() prints: ```fopen(): No such file or directory```